# How to start two spring boot apps

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

im playing with spring boot. So i wanted to create 2 microservices which interact with each other. My problem is that i cant start both of them, as the second app cant launch when the first one is already running with its own tomcat:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

How can i fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the port that the second application uses (to avoid the clash for the same TCP port).
One way to do that is to add a property like

```
server.port = 8090
```

to the `application.properties` of the second application

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to specify the port as a commandline switch.  This makes it easier to manipulate things at runtime w/o restoring to properties settings that may or may not be valid for the environment you are deploying to in the end.

```
java -Dserver.port=8081 -jar target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: I prefer this one much more. This makes the JAR much more manageable from an operations perspective.